# Wix Session Object

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Does anyone know at what point this object is still available?

I am trying to create a custom action called as follws:

```
         <Control Id="Test_Button" Type="PushButton" X="100" Y="100" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Test">
            <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="TestDatabaseConnection.SetProperties">1</Publish>
            <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="TestDatabaseConnection">1</Publish>
          </Control>
```

I have also defined

```
<CustomAction Id="TestDatabaseConnection.SetProperties" Property="TestDatabaseConnection" Value="CONNECTIONPROVIDER=[CONNECTIONPROVIDERNAME];PRIMARY_SERVER=[SERVER];PRIMARY_USERID=[USERID];PRIMARY_PASSWORD=[PASSWORD];"/>
<CustomAction Id="TestDatabaseConnection" BinaryKey="WixCustomActions" DllEntry="TestDatabaseConnection"/>
```

But I keep getting an error in the custom action, and it down to when I try and retrieve the set parameters.

I.e.

```
server = session.CustomActionData["PRIMARY_SERVER"];
```

boom it blows up

```
Action ended 13:11:46: TestDatabaseConnection. Return value 3.
DEBUG: Error 2896:  Executing action TestDatabaseConnection failed.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2896. The arguments are: TestDatabaseConnection, ,
```

This code works when put at the end of the execution cycle but now I want to call it when a button is pressed.

Any clues?

Comment: I have found the following:

http://goo.gl/gc9Az
'Only deferred, rollback, and commit actions use CustomActionData set 
from the matching property's value. Immediate actions (all UI actions 
are immediate) have full access to properties so this is unnecessary 
and unused. '

I have confirmed it doesn't fall over when i removed CustomActionData but I ahve experianced before that direct access to session via [] is handled better/silently and you just get an empty string, as you can not use session.log it is incredibly hard to debug!

Conclusion; it doesn't work but it doesn't fall over anymore.

Comment: OK i have given up trying to pass in using properties and am referring the actual variables; I was only trying to use the properties for consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only serialize and deserialize properties through a CustomActionData class for deferred CA's.  Immeadiate Ca's ( like when called from DoAction control events ) don't need this and it won't work.

Comment: So in summary you can not use SetProperties for 'immediate' actions like push buttons only for deferred.

Comment: Give this a good read if you haven't already: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm